# Не могу создать маршрут на карте от местоположения пользователя до определенного координата

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

помогите пожалуйста!!!
Не могу создать маршрут на карте от местоположения пользователя до определенного координата.
Чтобы создать маршрут нужно указать координаты. как указать координаты переменным. Переменная userCoodinates. с ума можно сойти. Мучаюсь  уже 3 дня.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var userCoodinates;
  var location = ymaps.geolocation;
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.755814, 37.617635],
    zoom: 14
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  });

  // Получение местоположения и автоматическое отображение его на карте.
  location.get({
      mapStateAutoApply: true
    })
    .then(
      function(result) {
        // Получение местоположения пользователя.
        var userAddress = result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text');
        userCoodinates = result.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
        // Пропишем полученный адрес в балуне.
        result.geoObjects.get(0).properties.set({
          balloonContentBody: 'Адрес: ' + userAddress +
            '<br/>Координаты:' + userCoodinates
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects)
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log('Ошибка: ' + err)
      }
    );

  var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    // Описание опорных точек мультимаршрута.
    referencePoints: [
      [userCoodinates],
      [55.677353, 37.632447]
    ],
    // Параметры маршрутизации.
    params: {
      // Ограничение на максимальное количество маршрутов, возвращаемое маршрутизатором.
      results: 2
    }
  }, {
    // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
    boundsAutoApply: true
  });




  // Добавляем мультимаршрут на карту.
  myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Определение местоположения пользователя</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=74d2d3f6-2cfa-47b1-85c3-f0abe32cec9b" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="geolocation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы получаете `userAddress` асинхронно внутри `location.get().then`, передавать координаты в `MultiRoute` надо там же. Можете перенести в колбек создание `MultiRoute` или задавать в колбеке координаты точек маршрута через [`setReferencePoints`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRouteModel-docpage/#method_detail__setReferencePoints):

```js
var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
  referencePoints: [], // Пустой маршрут
  // ...
});

ymaps.location.get({ mapStateAutoApply: true }).then(
  function(result) {
    var userCoodinates = result.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates;
    // ...
    multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([
      userCoodinates,
      [55.677353, 37.632447]
    ]);
  },
  function(err) { console.log('Ошибка: ' + err) }
);
```